# Editting field collections with service api

Tags: entities

I am trying to build an phonegap app which uses data of a drupal site. I need to update some informations with using app. For example I have nodes and users need to update field_collections of a node. My nodes have field collection as:

```
"field_bundle_news":{
    "und":[
    {
        0:{ target_id: "308" }
    }]
}
```

I want to add some additional items or remove some of them with using service api. For example if I use put method with using "/node" endpoint I can edit some data of that node but I can not edit field collections.

Could anybody give me information about this problem with examples because actually I dont know drupal well I am learning it with implementing a mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

You must send acceptable field structure in order to create or edit the node

try to understand the field structure through Implementing [hook_node_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) in custom module and  watchdog the inserted node via watchdog and you will have the structure drupal uses to insert then build it when you create/edit node through services

```
function hook_node_insert($node){
  watchdog('node', json_encode($node));
}
```

after adding a node of the same type open [dblog](http://admin/reports/dblog) in your project and see that log, you could use [pro.jsonlint](http://pro.jsonlint.com/)  to understand it well

Hope that helps

Comment: I don't want to create a node, I want to add a new item to that array with using api. On the other hand i can send acceptable field structure except this types of arrays for example i can edit other fields with sending data as ' "log" : "something" '. Could you give me an example url format or data format to edit this types of arrays.

Comment: I mean you first create a node with that field and see the log how the field structure is and try to build like

Comment: see that sandbox project it may help https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/graber/2141747

Answer (score 0):

Field collections are actually separate entities. They get attached to nodes, but the collections themselves exist separately. When you look at the endpoint for the node, you see that it just gives you an entity ID as the value.

There's a sandbox module that could potentially help:
https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/graber/2141747

Another alternative is to write your own resource endpoint that abstracts the field collection entity away for your specific project. In this example, you'd want to start with the noderesource.module file, as you wouldn't need your own schema definition:
https://www.drupal.org/node/783460